# How much energy would it take to take down a 747 using vibrations?

Tags: frequency, resonance, estimation, vibrations, aircraft

*Background Information:* All materials have a resonant frequency, which is the frequency at which they are most easily excited (vibrated). That's how glass is shattered using high-pitched sounds.

Assume that there is a Boeing 747 flying through the air, and a fighter jet pulls up next to it. The pilot in the fighter jet takes out a device that emits a sound at the resonant frequency of the hull of the Boeing 747.

**How much energy would it take (and is it possible) for the 747 to start vibrating so hard that it falls to pieces?**

Comment: For that one would have to know the precise engineering data about the plane, having said that, the self-resonance frequency of a large plane is likely to be so low that a small plane could not be used as an efficient acoustic source.

Comment: what is the purpose of this question ?

Comment: To get onto the TSA's watch list :). I'm just curious. I don't know much about the physics of vibration, and I want to learn more about it.

Comment: Look up [*aeroelastic flutter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeroelasticity#Flutter). This is a problem that aircraft engineers take seriously, and they have various methods to minimize it, such as putting weights in the control surfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say:

> All materials have a resonant frequency

but this is at best an oversimplification. Any system has a set of [normal modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mode) and if you apply  driving force at a frequency that matches a normal mode then you will get a resonance. However for any system significantly more complicated than a tuning fork there are many normal modes and non-linearities in the system allows energy to transfer between different normal modes. Add to this the effect of damping, and the result is that for complex objects it is rare that there are any strong resonances.

So it is unlikely that you can make a 747 fall to pieces just by applying a resonant driving force. Or at least not without ramping up the magnitude of the driving force until it smashes the plane just due to brute force rather than any resonant effect.

Answer (score 1):

> All materials have a resonant frequency

Well, sort of. In general, complicated structures will have many resonant frequencies where the amplitudes of any oscillations will have local maxima.

However, one of the jobs of structural engineers, and I would assume this would apply to aeroplanes too, is to find these frequencies and make sure that either (a) they cannot be excited or (b) they are damped sufficiently that the Q-factor is too low for the oscillations to build up to dangerous levels.

In the case of a 747, as they are flying I would think they are subjected to an extremely broad range of exciting frequencies, and therefore I am sure (aeroplanes generally don't break up in flight) that this problem has been chewed over and any resonances sufficiently damped to avoid such problems.